# Is there a common notion of $\mathbb{R}^n$, for non-integer $n$?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, metric-spaces, dimension-theory-analysis

This is not a very well-defined question.

Are there any standard constructions of metric spaces, parameterized by real-valued $n \ge 1$, such that:

1. When $n$ is an integer, the metric space is precisely $\mathbb{R}^n$.
2. When $n$ is non-integer, the metric space can be seen as a reasonable generalization of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  For example, perhaps it has [Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) of $n$.

Alternately, a non-existence result that you can't maintain some of the important properties of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in a generalization like this would be interesting to me.

Comment: you could say that $\mathbb{R}^x \simeq \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}/a \mathbb{Z}$ with $\alpha = \frac{1}{1+\lfloor x \rfloor - x}-1$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no topological space $X$ such that $X\times X\cong\mathbb{R}^n$ if $n$ is an odd integer.  You can prove this using homology; see, for instance, [this answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/60378/75).  In particular, this seems like pretty good evidence that there is no reasonable notion of "$\mathbb{R}^{n/2}$" when $n$ is an odd integer.  By similar homology arguments you can show that if $n$ is not divisible by $m$ then there is no space $X$ such that $X^m\cong\mathbb{R}^n$, so there is no good topological candidate for $\mathbb{R}^{n/m}$.

These topological obstructions aside, I can say that if there is a "common notion" of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for non-integer $n$, it can't be *too* common, because I've never heard of it.

Comment: +1 I wonder if, despite homology arguments against $\mathbb{R}^x$ for non-integer rational $x$, one can nevertheless define a natural topological space for $\mathbb{R}^x$ for some irrational $x$.